# ¿Cómo eliminar las carpetas que no fueron creadas en el año actual?

Tags: powershell

Estoy realizando un Script que tiene que borrar todos los ficheros de un directorio que no coincidan en el la fecha de creación con el año en el que se ejecuta, es decir, si lo ejecuto en 2017 que borre todo lo que no se haya creado ese año.

He conseguido sacar el año, pero no se como borrar los ficheros:

```
$yearOs = Get-Date -Format yyyy
$yearItems = Get-ChildItem E:\Backup\ | get-date -Format yyyy

foreach ($i in $yearItems) {
  if ($i -ne $yearOs) {
  echo $i # esto da cualquier fecha que no sea el año en el que se ejecuta
  }
 }
```

También he pensado en utilizar el comando `forfiles` pero ya os comento que en PS estoy un poco verde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con este script bastará

```
Get-ChildItem <ruta> |
    ? { $_.CreationTime.Year -ne (Get-Date).Year } |
    ForEach { Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $_.FullName }
```

> Nota: Reemplaza  por la ruta correcta de tu directorio, por ejemplo: `E:\Backup\`

#### Explicación:

```
Get-ChildItem <ruta> |
```

Esta línea obtiene los directorios hijos de `<ruta>`.

```
? { $_.CreationTime.Year -ne (Get-Date).Year } |
```

Esta línea hace un filtro (where) y devuelve solo directorios que no tengan como fecha de modificación al año actual.

```
ForEach { Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $_.FullName }
```

Esta línea recorre cada uno de los directorios del paso anterior y los elimina recursivamente (incluyendo todos sus subdirectorios).

Comment: Que errores te salen?

Comment: Los he publicado en una respuesta (aquí no podía por los carácteres)

Comment: Solo basta con que tengas permisos de escritura sobre la ruta correcta así sea de red

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes votarla como positivo y/o marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Le agregé `.FullName` al directorio para garantizar que lo encuentre así el script se ejecute desde una unidad diferente.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar

Comment: Pues ahora lo hace bien, solo, que lo elimina todo, lo creado en 2017 y 2016

Comment: La carpeta se llama 2017 o 2016 o te refieres a la fecha de creacion o de modificacion de la carpeta?

Comment: Siento ser pesado pero este script es por trabajo. Ahora no borra ninguno, también te comento que tuve que alterar las fechas de creación para que uno de los ficheros fuera del 2016, no se si eso tendrá algo que ver (el caso es que en la creación pone 2016)

Comment: No he dicho nada, el programa no modifico la fecha de creación si no la de modificación. Voy a probar!!

Comment: El script se basa en el nombre de la carpeta, nada tiene que ver las fechas del sistema de archivos, por eso era mi pregunta, ¿necesitas compararlos contra las esas fechas? (creación o modificación)

Comment: si, lo que necesito es que vea las fechas de creación de los ficheros y si no son del año en que se ejecuta (2017 ahora) que los borre. Por eso modifiqué la fecha de creación de uno de los ficheros, para que fuese del 2016 y sea el que se cargue el script.

Comment: Listo, cambié `.Name` por `.CreationTime.Year` en la condición para obtener lo que buscas

Comment: MIL GRACIAS!! me acabas de salvar un día de trabajo, soy nuevo aquí y no se como agradecértelo, pero para cualquier cosa que pueda estoy aquí.